# How to show a website in the contract scan page?

Tags: solidity

How is it possible to show a website in the contract scan page? Some contracts have a web address associated in the scanner page.

Answer (score 2):

It's a feature of the blockchain explorer sites, so each might have a bit different way (and some may not allow this feature at all).

**Etherscan**

1. Go to https://etherscan.io/tokenupdate
2. Sign in with your Etherscan account
3. Enter your contract address
4. If you're yet not verified as the creator or owner, Etherscan will ask you to sign a message from your creator/owner address

   - Example for USDT: [link](https://etherscan.io/verifyAddress/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7), [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppoVm.jpg)
5. Enter the website, token logo, and other info and submit the form

---

**BscScan**

Same, just with https://bscscan.io/tokenupdate